# vue how to assign value in html?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

This is my usecase:

```
<div v-if="getObject()">
    <div v-if="getObject().someBoolean">
        {{getObject().someOtherKey}}
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't want to be calling `getObject` everywhere so I'm wondering if there is a way to simply assign a value after calling `getObject` and then reusing that within the same div?

Note I can't use `v-for` since it iterates over the keys, and in my example I need 2 keys in the same iteration.

Comment: Change getObject to a computed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the return function of `getObject` as a computed property, then access it later.

**Edit**:

```
data: {
   ids: [],
},
computed: {
   objects() {
     return this.ids.map(getObject);
   }
}
```

Then you iterate over `objects`, instead your `ids`.

Comment: What if `getObject` is really `getObject(id)` and my function is used within `v-for` block that iterates over some ids?

Comment: I've made some edition with a suggest.

Also, see that link:

https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/2025

This feature doesn't exist because is bad in 99% percent of the cases.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like:

```
computed: {
  theObject () {
    return this.getObject()
  },
},
```

Then just use `theObject.whatever` in your templates.

Comment: What if `getObject` is really `getObject(id)` and my function is used within `v-for` block that iterates over some ids?

Comment: It sounds like each iteration should be its own component in that case. Otherwise, you could a computed property of them all and just loop through that like Edmundo suggests above.